# How to fix logo place in my website with css

Tags: html, css

I want to fix the place of the circle logo, how i can make it exactly like the designed final result that i share in below.

Final result:

[image: Final result]

html:

```
<nav></nav>
<header>
  <div class="logo">

  </div>
</header>
<div class="main">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Mohammad Mehrabi - محمد محرابی</h1>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, eius.</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
nav{
  height: 40px;
  background: #a1504b;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #8c4742;
}
header{
  background: #443a33 url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/az-subtle.png") repeat;
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #38302a;
}
.logo{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #202727;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border:1px #28221e solid;
  box-shadow:  0 0 3px #222;
}

.main{
  height: 1000px;
  background: #222 url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/az-subtle.png") repeat;
}

.title{
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.title h1{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.title h3{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fbc36a;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

live preview of my codes: http://codepen.io/mehrabi/pen/MKRVJg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely position the circle so it sits above the rest of the DOM. You can add the following to your `.logo` and it will work (note that you can center an absolutely positioned element by zeroing out the left/right CSS properties and setting the margin to `auto`):

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

I updated your codepen example, it now works:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/rxbvVm

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position` and then move around as you wish, check the sample: [codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxbvxw)

PS: the pixels are just to show you how, please change them to match your requirements

Comment: @MohammadMehrabi Glad i could help, please accept the answer if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

or you may use flex and a bit of negative margins:  http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/yerjMM

```css
/* CSS added */


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  flex: 1;/* add this to main if you want 50/50 height shared with header */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.logo {
  position:relative;  
  margin: 0px auto -75px;
  }
.title {
  margin-top:50px;
  }
/* end css added */

nav {
  height: 40px;
  background: #a1504b;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #8c4742;
}

header {
  background: #443a33 url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/az-subtle.png") repeat;
  height: 130px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #38302a;
  padding: 2px;
}

.logo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, white, #319DCC, #202727);
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px #28221e solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #222;
}

.main {
  background: #222 url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/az-subtle.png") repeat;
}

.title {
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.title h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

.title h3 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fbc36a;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<header>
  <div class="logo">

  </div>
</header>
<div class="main">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Mohammad Mehrabi - محمد محرابی</h1>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, eius.</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your codes work well but when i see the full page preview it doesn't have good result.

Comment: @MohammadMehrabi have you followed the codepen link ? (different settings). what should be the final-result actually when full page ?